# How to read PyQGIS documentation?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, references, pyqgis-3

As I get more into QGIS scripting, I refer to the documentation often and usually without success. I have trouble deciphering how to interpret the classes, etc.

I've been really struggling to create a New Print Layout and add things to it like the map, legend, label, etc. I have not gotten to trying to make things look nice yet, just the very basic functionality.

[Let's take the QgsLayoutItemLegend class for example from the documentation](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/Layout/QgsLayoutItemLegend.html):

Now, I think I understand that in order to create a legend item and add it to my Print Layout, I would do something like this...

```
QgsLayoutItemLegend.create(legend)
```

Except, I need to already have a legend item to "create" a legend in the Print Layout. But how do I create this legend item?

I don't only want to know how to create this legend item, but where in the documentation can I even find this?

Comment: In case you are having trouble understanding how classes work in general, this is a great tutorial that makes it very clear how classes work in python: https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/python/object-oriented-programming/classes-and-objects-i/tutorial/

Comment: This is a better reference for the QGIS api https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutItemLegend.html

Comment: the api page has links to the source for the classes, like this https://qgis.org/api/qgslayoutitemlegend_8cpp_source.html

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.

Comment: Ok, I'll modify the question